# How to show a popup to confirm update operation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

Using AspxGridView, I want to implement aspxpopup to confirm updating record.
I need to do some server-side data check with what user input before updating, and I can check that in server side grid.RowValidating event. After checking, how do I launch a aspxpopup afterward to let user confirm updating the record?

In summary, after user click Update button in EditForm, is it possible to include a Aspxpopup to confirm the Update, and base on user input, decide to execute or not execute grid.RowUpdating/grid/RowInserting event code?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#8d3736"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridheader">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton8" runat="server" CommandName="del"
                       ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png"
                       onclientclick="return confirm('Do You Want To Update?')"
                       onclick="ImageButton8_Click" />
  </ItemTemplate>
```